# Abridged Birkat HaMazon - Online?

Tags: sources-mekorot, product-recommendation, internet, bentching

HaRav Binyamin Kwalwasser from [Yeshivat Lev Hatorah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeshivat_Lev_Hatorah) taught us that [Rabbi Abadi](http://kashrut.org/grace/) is of the opinion that it is better to say a shorter version of Birkat Hamazon after eating than not to say it at all. (IIRC, R' Kwalwasser said that R' [Baruch Simon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baruch_Simon) from [YU](http://www.yu.edu/riets/faculty/roshei-yeshiva/) agrees with R' Abadi regarding this subject.)

My question is: Is this abbreviated form of Bentching available on the Internet, as a PDF file or otherwise?

Comment: BTW R. Henkin (senior; contemporary of R. Moshe) held this way too. He also has a short version of bentching in his Kesavim, though I don't have the source offhand or the sefer with me to check.

Comment: @DovF http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=2274&st=&pgnum=156

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link for the Android version of Rav Abadi's Birkat Hamazon. Visit: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cqlsys.birkathamazonhakatzar

Answer (score 7):

The words of Rav Abadi's version can be found as a PDF [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1525&st=&pgnum=63) (although the vowels are somewhat corrupted) in the text of the Teshuva (Or Yitzchak I OC 59) where he discusses the permissibility of using a shortened version.

Comment: He writes in the [responsa](http://kashrut.org/images/RESPONSA-01.gif) that it is based off the [nusach of the Rambam](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9713&st=&pgnum=291).

Comment: I wonder why he doesn't put "_amen_" after the third _b'racha_.

Comment: @msh210 Because the Rambam doesn't. http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/27.htm

Answer (score 1):

A Google search for "birkat hamazon short form" turns up several pages, including [this PDF](http://www.koshertorah.com/PDF/kitzur-birkat-hamazon.pdf) from Harav Ariel Bar Tzadok.  (Transliteration only, no Hebrew text.)  I don't know who he is, but the page includes contact information.