# Shortened Birkat Hamazon

Tags: tefilla, time, nuschaot, bentching

I see mentions of a short version of Birkat Hamazon ("Birkat Hamazon Hakatzar"). R [Yitzchak Abadi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchak_Abadi) wrote one "based on the Rambam and other Rishonim", [R Yosef Eliyahu Henkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Eliyahu_Henkin) is mentioned [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17909/abridged-birkat-hamazon-online) as having one as well and there might be others.

I knew of an [abbreviated](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos-2-mishneh-torah/263-the-abbreviated-shemoneh-esrei/) Shmonei Esrei but not of an abbreviated Birkat Hamazon and would like to learn more:

- Did a common *nusach* emerge?
- What have been views of other *poskim* regarding these proposals?
- Are there communities where it is mainstream to recite these abbreviated birkat hamazon *lechathila*?

*PS. This reminds me of a story I heard, maybe in the name of R Kotler, saying: "I don't understand why people say they don't have time for breakfast: 5 minutes to eat, 15 minutes for birkat hamazon and that's it!"*

Comment: possible dupe? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78051/759

Comment: You're not talking about the case, when you omit the Harachaman parts, right?

Comment: While Rabbi Abadi is advocating this not as the new norm.  Rav Henkin was not advocating this for adults, only for children.  The Chasam Sofer [printed in his siddur] also has a short version based on the Magen Avraham 193/1, but he too suggests this only בשעת הדחק not something to be used all the time by everybody.

Comment: @פריזהב I think R Abadi's point is people shouldn't be so worried to classify something as a shaat hadechak. Many people are so averse to doing anything possibly bedieved that they end up bentching very quickly with no kavana (at work, at restaurants, on public transportation, etc.) thinking they are being frum by not doing a bedieved thing. This is pure טפשות. A real חכם knows when he will be able to have Kavana and when he won't.

Comment: @DoubleAA - I"m not suggesting that Rabbi Abadi's reasoning is not sound, but he clearly advocates for everyone to say the short one all the time. He writes that since you are fulfilling your obligation with the short version, the overall good [that more people bench] overrides not saying the longer version, even though you are able to. Then, as a second point, he adds on your point. (See אור יצחק חלק א ד"ה ומה)

Comment: @פריזהב I don't have the teshuva in front of me right now, but doesn't he say that even if people who would have said the full version will now say the abridged version it is still better because they are still yotzei, plus others that wouldn't have said anything will now say the abridged version. I.e. he is not saying that everyone should specifically not say the long version; he's just saying that even if publicizing the short version causes everyone to say the short version it is better than not publicizing it.

Comment: @DoubleAA - You are right, I am wrong.  Still he is advocating a more widespread use of the shorter version than anyone else.

Comment: @Kazibácsi regarding the second comment above, I am actually now asking a question regarding this practice (https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94939/cut-off-birkat-hamazon) - maybe you have an answer?

Answer (score 3):

@Alex kindly directed me to [this audio shiur](https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/888876/rabbi-aryeh-lebowitz/ten-minute-halacha-abridged-versions-of-bentching/) by R Aryeh Lebowitz who discusses this question. In summary, he says that

- there have been a number of [*nuschaot*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78051/shortened-version-of-birkat-hammazon) (texts) proposed for a shorter *birkat hamazon*, originally for cases of urgency (*shaat ha'dchak*)
- recently, poskim such as R Yitzchak Abadi have suggested using them in all cases (*lchathila*), since people have a hard time concentrating for the whole length of *birkat hamazon*, arguing it is better to have more concentration for a shorter text
- he reminds us the gemara ([Brakhot 48b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.48b.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) writes the blessings of Birkat Hamazon were instituted by no other than Moshe, Yehoshua and David and Solomon
- the Tur, Beit Yosef and Shulhan Aruch give specific requirements for the minimum to be included; the Magen Avraham quotes an abbreviated text for birkat hamazon for urgent cases that satisfies all these requirements

Additional reasons why R Abadi suggested his text are that

- some people were using shortcuts and not saying *birkat hamazon* for certain foods (e.g., on pizza, or pita/falafel), chosing instead to say incorrectly *borei minei mezonot* and the relevant *bracha ahrona*
- everything one needs to say is in the shorter *nusach* so there is nothing to lose by saying it

R Lebowitz personally comes out against using such shortened texts. Interestingly, R Abadi himself doesn't use his own shorter *nusach* !

Comment: He doesn't discuss the in between option of only reciting the short version at work or something when for many bentching is done quickly and discreetly and with more fear or being caught than kavana. See too OC 192