# A recent siddur that includes an abbreviated birchas hamazon text

Tags: halacha, prayer-book, bentching, magen-avraham, nuschaos

Magen Avraham in OC 192 brings attention to the existence of an abbreviated birchas hamazon

> נוסח ב"ה הקצר להרב מהר"ר נפתלי בהסכמ' הרבה גדולי חכמים ברכה ראשונ' כולה כתיקונה ואח"כ יאמר נודה לך ה' אלקינו על שהנחלת לאבותינו ארץ חמדה טובה ורחבה ונתת לנו ברית ותורה ולחם לשובע בא"י על הארץ ועל המזון רחם ה' עלינו ועל ישראל עמך ועל ירושלים ועל מלכות בית דוד משיחך ותגדיל מהרה כבוד הבית ותנחמינו בכפלים בא"י בונה ברחמיו ירושלים אמן בא"י אמ"ה האל א"מ המלך הטוב והמטיב לכולנו הוא היטיב הוא מטיב לנו הוא גמלנו הוא גומלנו הוא יגמלנו לעד בחסד ובחן וברחמיו ויזכנו לימות המשיח עושה שלום וכו' עכ"ל ומכ"ש שיוכל לו' עד אל יחסרנו (ב"ח):

Does anyone know of an easily available siddur that has it?

Comment: https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1525&st=&pgnum=63

Comment: Thank you Dov (15)

Comment: https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=2274&st=&pgnum=156

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17909/759

Comment: Thank you @DoubleAA

Comment: In case anyone is interested in identifying הרב מהר"ר נפתלי, it is actually a matter of debate. There's a decent article exploring the possibilities in Hamebhaser Torani, 26 Iyyar 5772, p. 18-19.

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34254&st=&pgnum=1001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Siddur 'Aliyoth Eliyahu (Nusah Ashkenaz) has it on p. 150 (the pagination may be different in later editions).

If you purchase it on [R. Lopiansky's website](https://www.eshelpublications.com/store/p5/Siddur_Aliyos_Eliyahu_w%2F_Masores_Hatefilla.html), the US ground shipping is free. You can also find it being offered by other online retailers, but getting it directly is probably the most cost effective way to get it.

[image]

Comment: Very cool! Tyvm for that! This may be pushing it but do you happen to know if it also contains the abridged shemoneh esrei prayer havineinu?

Comment: @Nahum My pleasure. I'll be out for the next few hours, but I'll try to check later today or tonight

Comment: Ty, I'll keep an eye out

Comment: @Nahum I finally had a chance to check. It does indeed contain הביננו on p. 130. It's a shame that both are not more commonly included in siddurim.

Comment: really appreciate it. Indeed, it is.